# Android Q - Wifi connectionproblem with WifiNetworkSpecifier

Tags: android

On Android 10 (Q) I try to connect to a wifi without internet access with WifiNetworkSpecifier.

The first connection work without any problem. After that first connection I can't connect anymore.
Then I have to switch Off/On the wifi network again and than it works one time again.

This problem I have with a Xiaomi Mi 9 SE, with a Samsung Galaxy S10e the error does not exist.

How can I solve this problem, because I can't switch off/on the wifi programmatically on Android Q.

Has anyone a workaround for this problem?
My workaround is to inform the user to do a switch off/on by him self and start a panelIntent. But this is not a fine solution for me.

Here is my code:

On the init():

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP)
{
    NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    networkRequestBuilder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED);
    networkRequestBuilder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED);
    networkRequestBuilder.removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
                
    if (SDK_INT >= Q)
    {
        WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
        wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder.setSsid(ssid);
        wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder.setWpa2Passphrase(password);
                    
        WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder.build();
        networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);
    }

    networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
    networkCallback = new NetworkCallback()
    {
                    
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network)
        ...
                
    };
}
            
if (SDK_INT < Q)
{...}
```

... when the thread is running:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    NetworkBinding();

    while (runSendThread)
    {...}

    NetworkUnbinding();
}
```

... and the bindingMethodes:

```
public void NetworkBinding()
{
    try
    {
        if (SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            mConManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HandleException(e);
    }
}

public void NetworkUnbinding()
{
    try
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            mConManager.bindProcessToNetwork(null);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            mConManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
            android.net.ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HandleException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it? How?

Answer (score 0):

For others who have similar situations:
I have found out, that the problem was on the router which needed a firmware-update.
I think some newer phones try to find out if the network is ok and if they do not get the right response they mark the network as corrupt.
After the firmware-update, the connections work with every phone.